# Typescript function that takes a function and returns a function with subset of parameters

Tags: typescript, generics

So... this might be hard to follow but here it goes...

I want to create a function `f()` that accepts a function as it's parameter and returns a new function that has the same parameters **excluding** the first parameter (which can be concretely typed).

```
function f<R, A extends (s: string) => R>(func: A): () => R;  // no extra params
function f<R, T1, A extends (s: string, a1: T1) => R>(func: A): (a1: T1) => R; // 1 extra
function f<R, T1, T2, A extends (s: string, a1: T1, a2: T2) => R>(func: A): (a1: T1, a2: T2) => R; // 2 extra
function f(func: (...x: any[]) => any) {
  return (...x) => {
    return func('hello', ...x);  //call function.  'hello will always be passed as first param, followed by the rest
  };
}
```

In this example, `f()` should basically take any function where the first parameter is a string (`s`) and return a new function with 0 to 2 parameters (`a1` & `a2` if present in passed function; `s` will be excluded).

So if I were to pass:

```
function testFunc(x: string, y: number): number{
  return x.length + y;
}

const x = f(testFunc);
```

I would expect `x` to be type `(a1: number) => number`.  However, instead I'm getting `(a1: {}) => {}`...

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many free type parameters and it's messing up generic inference. The function should look like this (extra overloads omitted for brevity):

```
function f<R>(func: (s: string) => R): () => R;
function f<R, T1>(func: (s: string, a1: T1) => R): (a1: T1) => R; // 1 extra
function f(func: (...x: any[]) => any) {
  return (...x) => {
    return func('hello', ...x);  //call function.  'hello will always be passed as first param, followed by the rest
  };
}

function testFunc(x: string, y: number): number{
  return x.length + y;
}

// x: (a1: number) => number
const x = f(testFunc);
```

Comment: ahh thank you so much...  I think I understand...  basically the `A extends` was adding additional ambiguity to the types that was redundant... Not sure how I got down that path in the first place

Comment: do you have any idea if it's possible to get implicit types?  When I run `const x = f((x)=>5);` it properly identifies the type `x:string`. However, if I pass two params: `const x = f((x,y: number)=>5);` the type of `x` is now `any`

Comment: A function expression in an argument position for an overloaded function won't get contextually typed, unfortunately.